# What is the error in java code?

Tags: java, string

The code contains 4 methods 
  Dir is the constructor 
  addDetails is to get company Details , 
  contact number and  ratings for that particular company 
  and store it in arrays compName,compNumber and Rate respectively
  which are String array,Int array and String array respectively.

Method getDetails takes a name as input and prints details 
  of that particular company as output

Similarly getContact takes company name and gives contact number

```
public class Dir extends UnicastRemoteObject implements DirInterface {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    public String compName[]=new String[50];
    public int compNumber[]=new int[50];
    public String Rate[]=new String[50];

    public static int k=0;

    public Dir() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public void addDetails() {
    System.out.println("Input  company Details to add");
    compName[k]=sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("input contact number of company");
    compNumber[k]=sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("enter out of 5 for rating");
    Rate[k]=sc.next();

    k++;
}

public String getDetails(){
    System.out.println("Input company name to get its details");
    String name2=sc.next();

    for(int i=0;i<=(compName.length());i++){ 
        if(name2==compName[i])
            return compName[i]+" "+compNumber[i]+" "+Rate[i]+" rating";
    } 
}

public int getContact(){
    System.out.println("Enter name of the company to get contact number");
    String name1=sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<=compName.length();i++){
        if(name1==compName[i])
            return compNumber[i];
    } 
}
}

Errors:error ';' expected Dir() throws  RemoteException
cannot find symbol for(int i=0;i<=compName.length();i++)
symbol:method.length

error:incompatible types
location:return compNumber
required int found String

************SOLVED ERRORS OF THE ABOVE CODE*************



public class Client{
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
DirInterface st=(DirInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://"+args[0]+"/AddService");   

st.addDetails();

String det=st.getDetails();
System.out.println(det);

String xx=st.getContact();
System.out.println(xx);

}catch(Exception e){

System.out.println(e);
}

}


ERRORS:In Client class
Illegal start of type try{
expected ';'

Identifier expected 
st.addDetails();
sopln(det);

catch}(Exception e){}
class,interface or enum expected
```

Comment: **compName.length()** should be **compName.length** because its an array

Comment: You ask "what is the error". The compiler error essage tells that to you. No need to ask here. Just read the error message from the compiler. And if you don't understand it, then post it.

Comment: error is in the .length() method

Comment: BTW, beyond those errors, you have a hidden one `name2==compName[i]` <-- there as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the method `length()` is used to find out the length of a String, not of an array.

You should use `length` **without brackets** to find out the length of array, like this - `compName.length`

Then the method `getContact` should be String, like this -

```
public String getContact() ...
```

EDIT

Also, as pointed out by **Chief Two Pencil**, `name1==compName[i]` should be `name1.equals(compName[i])` as it's a String comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if(name2==compName[i])
```

will not work like you think it works. Do not compare strings with `==`, use `equals()` instead:

```
if(name2.equals(compName[i]))
```

See: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839)

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing the string you should use equals() method instead of ==.

For More Information follow the link.

[Compare String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html)

Answer (score -3):

You declared the arrays like this

String name[] = new String[5788];

but is has to be

String[] name = new String[5788];

Comment: i don't think this is the issue :)

Comment: The second way is the preferred way of declaring arrays in Java, but the first one will work as well.